# Fresco Library Issues

Tags: android, image, fresco

I'm using Fresco library for loading images and gifs into my application.  The big restriction I have encountered with Fresco is that the layout width and height have to be set.  So I have set up my simple drawee view like so:

```
 <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/feed_item_margin"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            fresco:actualImageScaleType="fitStart"
            android:layout_below="@+id/content_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/texture_view_height"
            fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/placeholder"
            />
```

My issue is if the image height is greater than the width there is a lot of white space left to the right of the image (see attached), however the height is fine

[image]

Then it can happen where the height if the actual image is less than the width (see attached) so here because the fixed height is 250dp there is a lot of white space below the image.

[image]

I have been through the different scaleTypes in the SimpleDrawerView and none seem to work to display the way I want to.

I'm wondering does anyone have much experience with Fresco?  I've started using this for loading gifs as I had an issue with Glide.

If anyone can help I'd greatly appreciate it.

FYI these images are streamed from a server, I have no control over the images

Comment: `fresco:actualImageScaleType="fitStart"` try removing this.

Comment: @vipul_asri I've already tried that, it just crops off the image...it's a really bad feature..

Comment: have you tried `android:gravity="center"`

Comment: it's a limitation with Fresco...a very bad one from what I can gather

Comment: You should definitely consider accepting the answer you have received.

Answer (score 7):

I am one of the authors of the Fresco library and I can probably help. From your question I don't actually know how would you like your images to be displayed.

First off, I would strongly suggest that you read the [documentation](http://frescolib.org/docs/using-drawees-xml.html#_) first. You will find that `android:scaleType` is completely ignored by Fresco and that you should use `fresco:actualImageScaleType` instead.

> My issue is if the image height is greater than the width there is a lot of white space left to the right of the image (see attached), however the height is fine.

If the height is fine, how is the extra horizontal space supposed to be populated? These are the **only** possible options:

- crop the image (e.g. `actualImageScaleType=centerCrop`)
- distorting the image so that it fills all the space (`actualImageScaleType=fitXY`)
- having blank space on one or both sides of the image (e.g. `actualImageScaleType=fitCenter`).

> Then it can happen where the height if the actual image is less than the width (see attached) so here because the fixed height is 250dp there is a lot of white space below the image.

Maybe the following would satisfy you. Set the layout params as following:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
fresco:viewAspectRatio="1.33"
fresco:actualImageScaleType="fitCenter"
```

This will make the drawee view have the width of the parent, and width to height ratio is going to be 1.33 (4:3) by default. 
Then you can programmatically set the aspect ratio to match the one of the image as I explained in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34075281/3027862). This will make drawee view height dynamically adjust based on the image.

Comment: am also using fresco to diplay images in a  listview. however, i have a concern. when i set `ActualImageScaleType` to `CENTER_CROP` and after scaling. the image height becames smaller than `simpledrawee` height, **there are spaces which are left in my simpledrawee view.**  **how can i get the height of scaled image and set it as height of my simple drawee view?**

Comment: This should not be the case. If CENTER_CROP scaletype is specified there should never be empty spaces left in the view. Can you post a screenshot and a code sample you are using?

Comment: here is my question and code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34874463/getting-the-height-and-width-of-scaled-image-in-fresco

Comment: please let me know when you have looked at my question in above link. am desperately in need of help.